# Find a continuous sequence of functions $f_n$ that does not converge but $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Construct a sequence of continuous functions $\{ f_n \}$ on $[0,1]$ such that $0 \le f_n \le 1$ and:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx &= 0 \\
> \end{align*}
>   but the sequence $\{ f_n \}$ does not converge at any point in $[0,1]$.

My work:

So for the first limit condition, functions with a $n^{-1}$ term or something similar will approach zero as $n \to \infty$. So we need $\int_0^1 f_n(x) \, dx$ to equal one of those. Functions like $1/n, x/n, x^2/n^2$ would all satisfy this condition.

For the second condition of a sequence of bounded non-converging functions would be $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$ or $f_n(x) = \sin n$ which can be easily scaled to fit the $[0,1]$ output interval:

\begin{align*}
  f_{1,n}(x) &= 1/2 \cdot [(-1)^n + 1] \\
  f_{2,n}(x) &= 1/2 \cdot [1 + \sin(n)] \\
\end{align*}

Now I'm having trouble finding a sequence of functions that satisfies both of these conditions at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f_n$ as the restriction to $[0,1]$ of an hat function centered at $|\sin n|$ with maximum $1$ and width $\frac 1 n$.

Comment: Note : this idea is just a particular case of Robert's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$f_1=\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1]},\quad f_2=\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/2]},\quad f_3=\boldsymbol 1_{[1/2,1]},\quad f_4=\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/4]},\quad f_5=\boldsymbol 1_{[1/4,1/2]},\quad f_6=\boldsymbol 1_{[1/2,3/4]},\quad f_{7}=\boldsymbol 1_{[3/4,1]},f_8=\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/8]}\quad f_9=\boldsymbol 1_{[1/8,2/8]},...$$

It's now easy to build continuous function based on this pattern (see my comment below).

Comment: These functions are not continuous as required but continuous approximations of them will work.

Comment: @RhysSteele: As written, it's a Hint. It's easy to construct a continuous sequence based on this pattern ! For example, $f_4=1$ on $[0,1/4]$, join linearly $1$ and $0$ on $[1/4,1/2]$ and is $0$ on $[1/2,1]$. Then $f_5$ joint $0$ and $1$ linearly on $[0,1/4]$ is $1$ on $[1/4,1/2]$, joint $1$ and $0$ linearly on $[1/4,3/4]$ and is $0$ on $[3/4,1]$... continue like that and you'll have your continuous sequence ;-)

Comment: I was not thinking about your hint the same way. I thought you suggested hat functions on the intervals you are defining. So for example for $f_2$ you would join $0$ to $1$ linearly on $[0,1/4]$ then $1$ to $0$ on $[1/4,1/2]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Following this way would lead for $f_n(1/2) = 0$ for all $n$ for example. And after this I saw your further description of the construction.

Comment: @nicomezi: Of course not ! $f_n(1/2)=0$ for infinitely many $n$ and $f_n(1/2)=1$ for infinitely many $n$ as well.

Comment: Well, not for the sequence I have talked about, also based on your suggestion. I just wanted to warn the OP about that "danger".

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try $f_n$ of the form
$$ f_n(x) = \max(1 - n |x - b_n|, 0) $$
where $b_n \in [0,1]$.  Choose this sequence so that every point of $[0,1]$ is in infinitely many of the intervals $[b_n - 1/(2n), b_n + 1/(2n)]$.